# Will top-level code execute before a page renders?

Tags: reactjs

Is it guaranteed that code in the top-level (like, not in a function) will run before the page starts rendering? For example:

In `src/common.js` we have:

```
import x from 'blabla';
x.init(someCredentials);
function doSomething() { ... }
function doSomethingElse() { ... } // etc. etc.
```

and in a component file we have:

```
import x from 'blabla'
function Component ({}) => <div>{x.get_something()}</div> // 'x.getSomething()' only works after calling 'x.init(...)'
```

My question is just this: are we guaranteed that `x.init(...)` has been called by the time our component loads?

And also, suppose we additionally have the following in `src/common.js`:

```
import x from 'blabla';
x.init(someCredentials);
export const actions = {get_something: () => x.get_something()}
```

Would it be safer/better to do the latter, and then import `actions` and call the methods on `x` via `actions.get_something()` even though it's kinda redundant?

Answer (score 0):

Technically yes. When `src/common.js` is imported elsewhere, the file will be executed, including `x.init()`, and its exports (`const actions`) will be made available to the importing file. The module will only be executed once, even if it is imported in multiple places.

Usually, if you need to initialize something before your app loads, you will want to do it early and at the top of your component hierarchy. In React, your root index.js or App.js file is a good place to do so.

So by importing `src/common.js` in your index.js, you would ensure that `x.init()` was executed before the first component was rendered, and then importing `const actions` elsewhere in your component hierarchy ensures that x has already been initialized once.

https://javascript.info/modules-intro

Comment: @AaronLevin did I answer your question?